# What is the correct interpretation of Revelation 2:4?

Tags: greek, revelation, translation-philosophy, hermeneutical-approaches, love

There seem to be several interpretations of the admonition of Jesus to the church at Ephesus.

Jesus first compliments the church at Ephesus for their labor, their endurance, their not tolerating evil, their testing and rejecting false apostles, their perseverance, and that they’ve endured for Jesus’ sake and have not grown weary!

Then, he says this in literal Greek from John the Revelator:

> “But I have this against you that the love of you first you have
> abandoned.”

See https://biblehub.com/interlinear/revelation/2.htm

Looking at how a variety of translators interpreted this verse, we read the following translations into English: https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Revelation%202:4

From these translations, we see several options:

a.  That they left/lost/ abandoned their first wives or their betrothed.

b.  That they left/lost/abandoned the love *for Jesus* that they had at the beginning.

c.  That they left/lost/abandoned the love they had *for each other* at the beginning.

d.  That they left/lost/abandoned the love *for the unsaved* that they had at the beginning.

e.  We’ll probably never know for sure in this life.

f.  All of the above.

What **hermeneutics principles and evidence** did you apply to arrive at a defensible conclusion that’s not simply an opinion?

Comment: @ Dieter I would eliminate option e) as one day we shall know. Since God does nothing , but he revealed his secret unto his prophets ( Amos 3:7) one could assume that all other of your options are viable, but not necessarily in that order. I agree with engineering mind on that . Now back to why I mentioned Amos 3, God knowing the past, present, and future may have used the book of Ephesians to give Ephesus instruction for the future. The book of Ephesians covers all of your options except e). Using Rev.2:5 spoken by Jesus himself places the focus on lack of works. Compliments to eng.mind.

Comment: How about "*That they no longer have the same enthusiasm or magnitude of love that they started with.*"? (Like the Laodiceans, but not as bad.)

Comment: @Ray Butterworth, Yes, a very reasonable hypothesis, and now we need supporting evidence. The Ephesians were complimented by Jesus on several important points. They didn't seem to be lacking in enthusiasm for labor, perseverance, rejecting false apostles, endurance, and not growing weary. So, putting myself in their place, I'm still looking for what "works" is Jesus telling me to resume?

Comment: [God's Church Through the Ages](https://www.tomorrowsworld.org/booklets/gods-church-through-the-ages/content#:~:text=However%2C%20after,purpose)
"*after the destruction of the Temple in Jerusalem in 70 AD, discouragement and spiritual lethargy set in. The brethren had expected Christ to return … now most of Judea and Galilee lay in ruins … Christians were considered traitors …
This era had left its first love, that early zeal for doing the Work. The membership began losing focus regarding those doctrines, practices, and priorities that gave them their true identity and purpose.*".

Comment: My previous comment, and this one, state, but don't give hermeneutical reasons for this view: [Seven Letters to Seven Churches](https://www.tomorrowsworld.org/magazines/2023/november-december/seven-letters-to-seven-churches#:~:text=Ephesus%20was,baptized.)
"*Ephesus was an actual congregation, composed of God’s servants, but had lost its “first love”—a common problem among those who have been Christians for some time and have lost the zeal they had when they were baptized.*"

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can separate options b, c, and d from each other given that the Biblical nature of love is that we love others as God has loved us (1 John 3:16, 1 John 4:11). So I think those three options are all true, but primarily option b since the others stem from it.

All the churches in Revelation are receiving a sort of audit from Jesus Christ on how they are doing spiritually. The contrast presented in this passage is between how good they are doing in the works they do (which you mentioned), yet at the same time how they have missed the most important virtue of the Christian life: love. Therefore they are in danger of having their church dissolved (their lampstand removed).

I think that because Jesus' command is to "repent and do the first works", this must be a reference to them living lives of faithfulness to God, and not faithfulness to wives. The church was doing well in the realm of observable works - "you cannot bear those who are evil". This makes infidelity to wives unlikely, since that would be blatant moral evil. However, almost ironically, they are commanded to "do the first works"; in contrast to the works they are already doing, they need the first works, which would be laboring with a heart of love for God.

Another point is that when we do see immorality addressed in the other churches, it is very explicitly mentioned (for instance, Pergamos and Thyatira).

In summary, the letter seems to be pointing to the contrast between external good works and apathetic internal heart attitude - something we should seek to be convicted by. The tree of life is for those who, as the bride of Christ, will be faithful to Jesus as their first and true love.

As always, keep asking questions and test people's statements like a Berean to see if what people are saying is in the Scripture.

Roughly speaking, the hermeneutics I used are let Scripture interpret Scripture, take it literally when the context supports a literal interpretation, and make sure similar sections are interpreted using the same principles.

Scriptures are from NKJV.

Comment: +1 Yes, I think you demolished the option a, "first love" as a reference to Malachi 2:14,15. You added the possibility of intentional ambiguity as a broader definition of "first love" or "love you had at first." Perhaps this abandoned love is an allusion to the duty-focused elder son in Jesus' parable of the prodigal son. But how do you know that the first love that the Ephesians abandoned was a feeling of love and not something different than a feeling. Verse 5 (ESV) reads, "Remember therefore from where you have fallen; repent, and do the **works** you did at first." What works were those?

Comment: @RHPclass79, I take pains to try to understand how a first-century reader would understand what Jesus was saying. I take more pains to try to make sure that I'm not force-fitting a theology into a passage, but let the passage and whatever allusions I can find in other parts of the scriptures teach me, hopefully with the guidance of the Holy Spirit. I also consider the words, linguistics, context, and culture guide me. So, what Greek word for "love" did John write down in the verses under consideration?

Comment: @Dieter It is agape. John uses it many times in 1John indicating that same love should flow through us or manifest through us. Can any conclusion be determined from the use of St.#25 agapao verse agape #26?

Answer (score 3):

The first hermeneutic principle that sprang to mind was the biblical principle of fact, that:

> "For the time is come that **judgment must begin at the house of
> God:** and if it first begins at us, what shall the end be of them
> that obey not the gospel of God?" 1 Peter 4:14 A.V.[emphasis mine]

That was stated some 30 years before the aged apostle John received the revelations of the outworking of that principle with the seven congregations of Christians in Asia Minor. It is highly significant that the first verse John wrote was to declare that he was being shown "things which must shortly come to pass". And, after the stupendous vision of Christ, the Alpha and Omega, standing in the midst of seven golden candlesticks, he was told that "the seven candlesticks which thou sawest are the seven churches."

That is the context, which is the other vital hermeneutic principle required to delve into more detailed understanding. But briefly going back to the first point, note how the apostle Peter referred to Proverbs 11:31, and there's also a connection to Jesus' prophetic warning about a coming time when people would cry to the mountains to fall on them, to hide them - a theme in Revelation (see Luke 23:30-31).

Now I quote from a book that begins to open up the book of Revelation with a stark warning as to interpreting meanings, before showing a principle that applies to all seven churches addressed by Christ:

> "Anyone presuming to use analytical methods or systematic reasoning to
> open the book may as well close it immediately, and permanently, for
> such matters will yield nothing to this procedure... Revelation is
> mysterious in its utterance, divine in its nature, heavenly in its
> origin, and spiritual in its interpretation." *The Revelation of Jesus
> Christ*, John Metcalfe, p.41,
> http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

This does not bode well for a strictly hermeneutic approach, but I will try to accommodate the request in the question as far as possible.

> "It follows that in principle, these churches were representative of
> those conditions on  which judgment was passed for the duration of the
> age [until Christ returns]... Any fool can take some so-called message
> from any one of the seven letters, applying it to 'his' church. The
> favourite is 'Thou hast left thy first love'. They ignore that fact
> that this was addressed in the second person singular to the angel,
> and not to the church of Ephesus at all.
>
> Nor is this everything. For a truth of the greatest moment
> conveniently ignored and wilfully forgotten by these people is that
> there was but one church in any given location. ...however, there
> exists a considerable number of various denominations all clustered
> together in the same place - each calling themselves 'churches' -
> instead of that one church alone in the entire locality." (*Ibid*. p.61)

***My answer is "b",*** but it would take many more quotes from that book to explain why. I have simply flagged up a cautionary way of approaching the question due to difficulties that arise from a purely hermeneutic approach - which I don't recommend.

Comment: +1 Great points as usual, @Anne. Let me note that there were many more churches in Asia than just these seven. Jesus picked them for a reason. Also, Revelation is full of allusions to the *Tanakh* and is, after all, called "the revelation of Jesus Christ" rather than the "obscuration of Jesus Christ," so I'd expect that the Jesus communicates to his beloved bride a spiritual painting that transcends the centuries and *secular* intellectualism based on flawed worldviews.

Answer (score 0):

Rev 2:4 is part of a series of NT verses that allude to the spiritual marriage of Jesus to the church. That is, the church (corporately) is often represented as the bride of Christ.

Indeed, this common theme is used as a metaphor for God’s people who are either faithful and pure, or, rebellious.  These include:

- The parable of the two adulterous sisters and their children (Eze 23)
- The daughter of Babylon vs the daughter of Zion (Zech 2:7, 10).
- More generally, the Old Testament uses this image of a woman to represent either faithful (Isa 62:5, Jer 2:1, 2) or unfaithful (Isa 47:1-3, Jer 2:32, Eze 16, Nah 3:4, 5) groups of people.  See also Gal 4:21-31 which used Sarah and Hagar as metaphors.
- In the book of Revelation, we have two women: Jezebel or the harlot as a symbol of Babylon (Rev 2:20, 17:1-18:24), vs, the pure woman as a symbol of God’s faithful people the bride of the Lamb (Rev 12:1-17, 19:7, 21:9).

Viewed this light, the church of "Ephesus" is portrayed as having lost their first love for Jesus which should have been their highest love and duty.  hence, of the OP's options, I would select option "b".

This conclusion is essentially confirmed by recognizing the opening statement about the whole subject matter of the book of Revelation - it is a "Revelation of Jesus Christ".  Thus, all seven vision on the book of Revelation is designed to teach us something about Jesus and our relationship with Him and His salvation and love for us.

Thus we must serve Jesus alone and no one else.  Indeed, the church of Ephesus is commended: "I know you are enduring patiently and bearing up for my name’s sake, and you have not grown weary." (Rev 2:3)

Comment: +1 for your supporting biblical references. But let me challenge you with this: how would we (or the Ephesians) *know* that they had lost either the love they had for Jesus *at the first*, for their *first love* who was Jesus (implying a love for someone or something else), or the love they were commanded to have for each other (John 15:9-13)? Is this love primarily a feeling, a priority, or a behavior? Does the Greek grammar suggest a preference for one of these options? Yes, I study these passages with some intensity and no slight is intended here. :-)

Comment: verse 2:5 may well be the key. For Jesus to threaten to remove their candlestick lest they repent sounds very serious. Neglect of God's will to do the works they originally did speaks of both quenching the Holy Spirit as well as the resultant sin of omition. That would be different for each individual as per their spiritual gift.

Comment: @RHPclass79, Ok, and what does Jesus tell the church at Ephesus would be the remedy? And  how would this remedy re-establish the love that they had abandoned?

Comment: @Dietet Repent- meaning first they would have to either realize they had sinned or if they were already aware they would have to return to their original priorities either way.